# Angular Material MatSpinner how to make background greyed-out

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material2

I have a loader component, loader component html which has show = true/ false. I am trying to include matSpinnner which is working just fine when I include in app.component.html but the background is not greyed out.

loading.component.html:

```
<div class="spinner_container"><mat-spinner *ngIf="show"></mat-spinner></div>
```

.css

```
 .spinner_container {
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 70px;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 70px;
    z-index: 3;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

in app.component.html:

```
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-loader></app-loader>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Here app-loader is the loader component which I am placing in app.component.html, but how do I make the background of my application background grayed out, so that user cannot click on any controls until spinner goes off.

Here is the image of my spinner , it works fine except that all background controls are accessible and not grayed out.

[image]

Comment: add a div as a background and use that as a full screen overlay

Comment: @TroyBryant can you share that piece of CSS changes that you are suggesting ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do something like this :

```
  .dark-overlay{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    position: absolute; <--fixed as per the suggestion below
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height:805px; <-- make this div height or adjust to full page height
}
```

Then you can just toggle the class display off and on with the spinner

Comment: If your content extends beyond the bottom of the screen, use `position: fixed;` instead.  This will keep the screen greyed-out even if the user scrolls down

Comment: I wrapped the mat-spinner in a div and changed height to 100%.